# TinyMCE 4.6 - Named Character References

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

i'm unable to use named references in TinyMCE 4.6, every time I enter one HTML tag in plain text it is converted to HTML and i dont want that.
For example, if I have `&lt;b&gt;&amp; aaaa&lt;/b&gt;` on the textarea, TinyMCE will just read it as HTML tags and not jut plain text.

Demo here : https://codepen.io/seltix/pen/LLGxMG

```
   <textarea>
    <table><tr><td>
         HTML
     </td><td>
         <b>& aaaa</b>
     </td></tr><tr><td>
         HTML encoded entities
     </td><td>
         &lt;b&gt;&amp; aaaa&lt;/b&gt;
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   </textarea>
   tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea',
     entity_encoding : "raw"
   });
```

how can i prevent that? if a user write HTML tags in text mode it just should save it as HTML entities.

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing raw HTML inside a `textarea` for TinyMCE you need to encode the HTML so the line in question needs to be more like this:

```
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;&amp; aaaa&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

It is likely easier to use the `setContent()` API to insert the content via JavaScript as that does not require you to encode things.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply! and tinyMCE has no setting to control this? i think this is a WYSIWYG issue since if a user write a html tag next time tinyMCE reads the code it will read it as a tag and not just as text. Should i report it in tinyMCE github?